# ¿Cómo puedo pasar los datos obtenidos a la hora de realizar una detección de objetos en un video a un fichero.txt o a un archivo.csv?

Tags: python-3.7, estructuras-de-datos

Realizo esta pregunta, ya que al pasar el detector de objetos a tiempo real por un video, conforme ejecuto el detector me muestran todos los datos que me identifican el tipo de objeto y la efectividad en porcentaje con la que lo reconoce, junto en el instante que lo ve y diversos valores mas, lo que yo quiero es sacar esos valores obtenidos en mi ejecución y pasarlos a un fichero.txt o .csv para guardarlo de forma automática cada vez que corra el detector.

Comment: Ya probaste usando la funcion built-in open? Y el modulo de la biblioteca estandar csv?

Comment: Como Dante menciona, qué has intentado hacer?